# The tags don't appear in AWS Cost Explorer's Filter section after activating them in Cost Allocation Tags of Billings console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing, aws-cost-explorer

After activating tags in "Cost Allocation Tags" of "Billings" console, they don't appear in the "Filter" section of "Cost Explorer".

I have activated the tags in Cost Allocation Tags of Billing console as shown in this screenshot [Cost Allocation Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n4MG.png)
but they do not appear in the Filter part of Cost Explorer as shown in this screenshot.[Filter - Cost Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9I81.png)
The AWS documentation says it can take up to 24 hours. [Using AWS cost allocation tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html#:%7E:text=All%20tags%20can%20take%20up%20to%2024%20hours%20to%20appear%20in%20the%20Billing%20and%20Cost%20Management%20console.)
I waited more than a week on the first time. After that, I have deactivated and activated the tags multiple times and have waited more than 24 hours each time but they still didn't appear on any of those times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the issue was. After the activation of the tags, if the services with that tag have not incurred any costs, it will not show in the cost explorer. But, once it starts incurring some costs, it will appear.